# What creating batch file fails in my python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-file

I am studying `automate the boring stuff with python` book and therein after finishing the `password locker` project it is suggested to create a batch file using the following codes:

```
@py.exe C:\Python34\pw.py %*
@pause
```

and I did exactly the same mine one looks like this (copied entire script if there are any other potential errors):

```
import sys
import pyperclip 
    """ PASSWORD LOCKER """

passwords = {
    'facebook' : 'password of facebook', 
    'gmail' : 'password of gmail', 
    'quora' : 'password of quora'
}

if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    account_name = sys.argv[1] 
    if account_name in passwords:
        print('Password of [' + str(account_name).upper() + '] has been copied to clipboard.')
        acc_password = passwords[account_name]
        pyperclip.copy(acc_password)
        print('Paste it anywhere')
    else:
        print('There is no name registered with that account name.')    

@py.exe 'C:\py\Automate the Boring Stuff with Python\Data Structures, Dictionary\pw.py' %*
@pause
```

then saved the file as `pw.bat`, according to instruction of the book:

> With this batch file created, running the password-safe program on
>   Windows is just a matter of pressing win-R and typing pw .

I then followed these steps again and it didn't work fine. Can you please help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have `py.exe`? The usual name of the Python interpreter on Windows is `python.exe`.

Comment: after reading the answer, yes I have it installed

Comment: You are aware that only the bottom two lines of your code are for the [tag:batch-file] aren't you?

Comment: yes, I just figured that out

Comment: how do I open `.bat` file? I clicked on it and it states `press any key to continue` and upon pressing any key it exits the program.

Comment: Right click then edit; to run, just double click. If it fails to run, then there is something wrong with the code

Answer (score 1):

Here are troubleshooting steps I'd suggest:

1. Ensure `py.exe` exists in environment path of your computer. The book may have installation instructions that may have been skipped inadvertently. If you know `py.exe` exists on your computer, but when you execute `py.exe` on opening a command prompt, you may see:

   `'py.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

   If you see the above message, this implies, you need to do either of the following:

   a. Change your batch file to say:

   ```
   `@<drive:\path\to>\py.exe`
   ```

   where the part `<drive:\path\to>` is the path to your python executable (`py.exe`), OR,

   b. Add the path to `py.exe` to the environment variables. Comprehensive instructions are [here](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html) for Python 3.
2. The way you have framed the question seems to suggest that you saved the entire code in one file `pw.bat`. If you did, you need to ensure the following:

   a. Last two lines of the your code snippet are in a file `pw.bat`, AND,

   b. Rest of the code is in the file `C:\py\Automate the Boring Stuff with Python\Data Structures, Dictionary\pw.py`.
3. The instruction below is correct only if the file `pw.bat` is in the environment path and thus *visible* to the operating system:

   > With this batch file created, running the password-safe program on Windows is just a matter of pressing win-R and typing pw

   If you do not know whether this is true or not, you will need to find out where you saved `pw.bat`. Open a command prompt and navigate to that location, and then execute `pw`. Issues pertinent to this are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows).

Comment: Okay, I guess the second part was the problem.

Comment: how do I open `.bat` file? I clicked on it there is nothing shown there. Just stating press any key to continue and upon pressing any key it exits the program.

Comment: Two ways: (a) double clicking (which is what you did). It shows the output followed by what you mention ("press any key to continue") which is the result of @pause, (b) open a command prompt, go to the location where your batch file is (via command 'cd <your/batch/file's/path>'), run the batch file by typing the name of the batch file.